# re.search : a lack of understanding through 2 examples

Tags: regex, string, python-3.x

```
if re.search("Vitamin B2 (Riboflavin)","Vitamin B2 Riboflavin,Riboflavin,Vitamin B2,Vitamin B2 (Riboflavin)") : print("ok")
```

Output:
`ok`

```
if re.search("Crude protein (min.)","Crude protein,protein,Protein,Protein    (crude),Crude protein (min.)") : print("ok")
```

Output :`none`

Why is that so? I dont see any formatting between those two examples. Or major differences, like spaces, coma or whatever. 
Why are those two exemples so different.

More details: I'm just trying to know if a string from a table A (eg. a list A) `"Crude protein (min.)"` is in a string of string like `"Crude protein,protein,Protein,Protein    (crude),Crude protein (min.)"`from a table B (e.G a list B) 
But in fact I've built table B in order to it to contain every string from table A so I was really expecting those exemple to work every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(`, `)` and `.` are special regex meta characters that need to be escaped in your regex:

```
if re.search(r"Crude protein \(min\.\)","Crude protein,protein,Protein,Protein    (crude),Crude protein (min.)") : print("ok")
...
ok
```

Your regex:

```
Crude protein (min.)
```

is attempting to match `min` and any character after `Crude protein` and a space. It won't match literal `(` and `)` as `(min.)` means a capturing group in regex.

**EDIT** You can use [`re.escape`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.escape) to escape all special characters for you:

```
if re.search(re.escape("Crude protein (min.)"),"Crude protein,protein,Protein,Protein    (crude),Crude protein (min.)") : print("ok")
...
ok
```

Comment: So it would be a lot easier for me to just search the string with the `find` function available with strings in python. Because i don't know in advance what meta character it's gonna contain. Well there is `), `(` and `'` , `:`, `:`. I would have to make a conditional formatting of the string before searching in it. Wouldn't it be more efficient to just `find` ? e.g `Crude protein (min.).find("Crude protein,protein,Protein,Protein    (crude),Crude protein (min.)")`, would it ?

Comment: Yes you can use `find` but remember that [`find` returns the lowest index in the string where substring sub is found.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find)

Comment: Also see my updated answer. You can use `re.escape` to escape all special characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
if re.search("Vitamin B2 (Riboflavin)","Vitamin B2 Riboflavin,Riboflavin,Vitamin B2,Vitamin B2 (Riboflavin)") : print("ok")
```

It prints ok, because `Vitamin B2 (Riboflavin)` matches `Vitamin B2 Riboflavin` `()` called capturing group which captures the text matched by the pattern present inside the capturing group,

where as,

```
if re.search("Crude protein (min.)","Crude protein,protein,Protein,Protein    (crude),Crude protein (min.)") : print("ok")
```

fails because it fails to find `Crude protein min.` dot means any char.

So you have to escape all the regex special meta charcaters in-order to match it's literal form. `\(`, `\)`, `\.`